# Applying script to input on Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to use Place Autocomplete from Google to an input that is part of an Angular 2 template. I know I can access the element using ElementRef but it doesn't seem to be the best way and I want to do my best with this.
To test a different approach, instead looking for the element I want to apply the script to I used a click event like this:

```
<input type="text" id="city" (click)="initializeCityInput($event)" />
```

Then on my angular component I have:

```
initializeCityInput(event) {
    let input: HTMLInputElement = event.currentTarget;
    let options = {
        types: ['(cities)'],
        componentRestrictions: { country: 'au' }
    };
    let autocomplete = new this.w.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
}
```

This works pretty well! But the thing is that I have to click my input to load the Autocomplete script.

Is there any event like 'load' for inputs or workaround so the script is loaded straight away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a template variable (`myInput`) to an element in your template you can access that element using `@ViewChild('myInput')`. It returns an `ElementRef` and its `nativeElement` is a reference to your input element:

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  template: `
    <input #myInput type="text" id="city" />
  `
})
class MyAutoComplete {
  @ViewChild('myInput') myInput;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.initializeCityInput(myInput)
  }

  initializeCityInput(event) {
    let options = {
        types: ['(cities)'],
        componentRestrictions: { country: 'au' }
    };
    let autocomplete = new this.w.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(myInput.nativeElement, options);
  }
}
```

See also [angular 2 / typescript : get hold of an element in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template)

Comment: Great, thanks for that. The function should be called inside ngAfterViewInit right? this.initializeCityInput(myInput)?

Comment: Right! Sorry, forgot to add that line :-/